# change Axis domain/range doesn't work in nvds

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying nvd3 example at http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav
Please click on plot 2 "Scatter/Bubble Chart".
Original Code for JavaScript is like:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
            .showDistX(true)
            .showDistY(true)
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data(4,40))
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart);

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

return chart;
});
```

I tried to change `xAxis` range/scale/domain to see if it has anything. But somehow it doesn't work.

What I did was to add

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1]).range([1,4]);
chart.xAxis.scale(xScale);
chart.xAxis.tickValues([1,2,3]);
```

below yAxis line in original plot.
I can see tickValues work as expected. But somehow both domain and range doesn't work as expected.

I would like to see xAxis to start from a different value like 1 or 0. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
chart.forceX([minValue,maxValue])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that too. The negative part still shows up. I guess something is wrong in my setting. But I just can't find out.

Comment: Could you put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so someone can have a look at, and help you out.

Comment: thanks for paying attention. I made some change. nvd3 site has some in place change capability so I just use that. It's a very simple change. I just don't see where my mistake is.